# Default Route for Svelte-Navigator?

Tags: javascript, routes, frameworks, svelte

I'm using svelte-navigator to handle routing in my Svelte application, and I have the issue that when accessing a route that I have not defined, it still loads the header and sidebar etc (which are outside the routes) - Is there a way to set a default route, so that when accessing an undefined route, it can redirect to the home page etc?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation

```html
<!--
  Routes without a path are default routes.
  They will match if no other Route could be matched
-->
<Route component="{Home}"></Route>
```